# android tablelayout fixed columns - not getting desired results

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tablelayout

I am new to Android development.

I've tried with `LinearLayout` and now finally with `TableLayout`.

I need a simple fixed scrollable table with 3 columns, but I can't get the single list rows to do what I need...I have the `ListView` and `ListActivity` with its `Adapter` sorted.

Basically I want:

- 3 columns with all fixed widths, but adjusting to different screen
  sizes (thus percentages?)
- The first column has a title and should be the largest. If the text exceeds the space, ellipsize it
- The second column is the price
- Third column is an icon and should be to the far right

> ```
> |-----------------------------------------|
> | This title exceeds th....|  $500 | Icon |
> | This title fits          | $1000 | Icon |
> | Other title              |   $25 | Icon |
> | Another long title th... | $1200 | Icon |
> |-----------------------------------------|
> ```

This is my latest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="A long Title it is"
            android:textSize="24sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/cart"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/cart"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" >
        </ImageButton>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The result is that sometimes the icon is not to the far right, and the title text has not a fixed width...

I have searched many questions and tried many things (see `layout_weight`) but it doesn't seem to work so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a table row(or horizontal orientation of linear layout) it is advised to use `android:layout_width="0dp"` while dealing with `android:layout_weight`

Could you please try setting layout_width attribute to 0dp. I think it'd work.

Comment: unfortunately not. now I see only the first two characters of the first column and the rest disappears for some reason

Comment: You mean the text in the title column ?

Comment: I had imported your layout. Worked perfect for me just by setting the width values to 0dp. Can you try increasing the weight value for the title?

Comment: Yes in the title column, for all rows now I see only the first two letters and then nothing, like if a shadow would be above everything. I increased the weight for the title column to 20 - no effect. I have the feeling it is smth very stupid...

Comment: You have set the width of other colums to 0dp as well right ?

Comment: yes, and in the design preview in android-studio it looks just fine! only when I run it on my S3 all rows now just show the first two letters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75251/discussion-between-jayesh-elamgodil-and-faboolous).

Comment: hey! I think I got it now. I use a ListView with a ListAdapter. The ListView which then dynamically constructs the TableLayout when results appear had `layout_width="wrap_content"`. I changed it to `fill_parent` and now it really is fine! But I'll accept your answer because it contains the actual correct response for the layout needed! Also thanks for your help.